# Java11 Migration - compilation error, Symbol$ClassSymbol cannot be cast to class Symbol$MethodSymbol

Tags: java, java-8, compiler-errors, migration, java-11

I am trying to migrate my application from java 8 to java 11 but am facing an error that I cannot get through:

```
compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.7, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol cannot be cast to class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$MethodSymbol (com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol and com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$Me
thodSymbol are in module jdk.compiler of loader 'app')
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitApply(TransTypes.java:626)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1634)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:454)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitVarDef(TransTypes.java:499)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:956)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1020)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:454)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitLambda(TransTypes.java:540)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1807)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:454)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translateArgs(TransTypes.java:200)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitApply(TransTypes.java:639)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1634)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:454)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitVarDef(TransTypes.java:499)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:956)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:167)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1020)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:454)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitMethodDef(TransTypes.java:489)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:866)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitClassDef(TreeTranslator.java:139)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translateClass(TransTypes.java:918)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.visitClassDef(TransTypes.java:475)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:774)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translate(TransTypes.java:454)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TransTypes.translateTopLevelClass(TransTypes.java:942)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1553)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1432)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:973)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:113)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:46)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.FlatClassLoaderWorker.execute(FlatClassLoaderWorker.java:31)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:56)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:118)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have tried to add modules with `compilerArgs`:

```
compilerArgs.addAll(['--add-modules', 'jdk.compiler'])
compilerArgs.addAll(['--add-modules', 'java.compiler'])
```

But that didn't resolve my problem either.

I am using gradle 5.6 to build.

Comment: Suggestion: don't try to jump 3 major versions at once. If you jump one at a time, 8 to 9, to 10, to 11, then you will more precisely be able to identify what has caused the incompatibility. Oracle publish a migration guide for each version increment. They don't publish such a guide for arbitrary jumps, e.g. 8 to 11, 7 to 14, etc.

Comment: @Michael: Actually, the LTE versions are 8 and 11. Therefore, a jump from 8 to 11 is not an arbitrary but the most frequent one.

Comment: @Nikolas I know that. It doesn't mean that you can't make the change incrementally, and it doesn't mean that Oracle publish a migration guide for it, because they don't. In their own words "*Before migrating your application to JDK 11, **you should understand what the updates and changes are between it and the JDK 10 release***"

Comment: Hi, little update: As @Michael have suggested - I've tried to run my application on Java 9/10. 
It compiled without any errors. So the problem is with Java 11.
I attempted to run my app on different versions like 11.0.2 / 11.0.3 / 11.0.7 / 11.0.8 but those didn't work either.